# docker swarm: A stack just for shared networks

Tags: docker-swarm, docker-network

I have many docker compose files which describe multiple stacks (Application, Monitoring infra, Logging Infra, Some other application). Some of these stacks need to share a network.

Since the dependencies between the stacks (X needs Y to start fist, Y needs Z) are becoming more and more complicated I wanted to introduce one stack that contains all the networks that will be shared so that I can then deploy all stacks in any order.

```
  version: "3.1"

  networks:
    iotivity:
    proxy:
```

Unfortunately a compose file like this doesn't create the networks. It doesn't throw an error but nothing is created. Does someone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: What is the benefit of having such a compose file? If it is just to create the networks, why not create a script that the creates these networks?

Comment: I can't come up with a non 'esthetic' reason not to use a script. I guess I'll stick with good old bash

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/. This might be useful if you want to refactor the compose files.

Comment: Thanks but its not supported in version 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dummy image. Dockerfile (copied from [Mailu](https://github.com/Mailu/Mailu/blob/master/core/none/Dockerfile)):

```
# This is an idle image to dynamically replace any component if disabled.

FROM alpine

CMD sleep 1000000d
```

Most probably a script is still more elegant. Just pointing out the possibility.